# Nodejs Express: Unrecognized content-type

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, express

I'm attempting to send a file from a phonegap application to a nodejs server and am having problems with the content-type of the request headers.

```
Error: unrecognized content-type: multipart/form-data;boundary express=++++++
```

The code is taken directly from the [example](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) at Phonegap. When the server receives the request, it throws the above error. Any idea what could be causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the multiparty library version you are using requires there to be a space in between the semicolon after form-data and boundary. Information on how to fix it is located at [here](https://github.com/amitaibu/node-multiparty/commit/37c25c9317fa19ca7ba0b58d47b7a8f42142c189#commitcomment-4241353). Either update to use that version or change the file manually yourself, nested in the node_modules folder in your app.